# Has/have the leaves been raked?

Tags: sentence-structure, subject-verb-agreement

This is a question about subject-verb agreement. I am having difficulty in deciding which version is correct.

Which one is correct? And why?

> (Has, have) the leaves been raked?

Comment: Is the subject **(the) leaves** singular or plural? The answer is super easy. Now, if you heard one of the two versions and you think it may be wrong, could you provide more details? For example, where did you hear it uttered? Or did you create this sentence yourself? Or did you read it online/exercise book/novel etc.?

Comment: Have you done any research beforehand? Searching "subject-verb agreement" gives you many information! I know that you're new to this site, so please read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, subject-verb agreement is very easy.

The basic rule is: A singular subject (he, James, cat) takes a singular verb (is, runs, eats), whereas a plural subject (they, Mia and Amy, the dogs) takes a plural verb (are, run, eat).

After knowing the rule of subject-verb agreement, let's solve your problem.

> **(*Has*, *have*)** the leaves been raked?

Do you know that answer now? It's

> ***Have***

Why? Because **the leaves** is plural. A *plural* subject takes a *plural* verb form.

I found some [exercise](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar_quiz/subject_verb_agreement_1.asp) online, if you are still unsure about whether you fully understand or not, you can practice them. And if you have any questions after doing the exercise (or any questions about this answer), just tell me in the comments :)